# Multi color post title by using custom javascript inside the gutenberg editor?

Tags: customization, javascript, block-editor

I'm just getting started with the gutenberg editor.

I want the editing person to be able to select parts of the post title wich then opens a toolbar above the selected textpart letting you choose a color from the color palette. The idea is to then wrap the selected text part in, idk, html-comments or maybe spans directly to set the color.

The problem is the only thing I know is how I can enqueue javascript for the backend so it is available in my gutenberg editor.

But how would I go about this? There is the Javascript 'wp'-object which might be helpful? I don't really find any resources that show how something similar to what i described above works.

Comment: HTML inside post titles is generally not possible unless you're an administrator with `unfiltered_html` allowing you to bypass security checks. It's likely for most users any spans or HTML comments will get stripped out on save, and then again on display. Also if you're hoping to directly modify the post title HTML in the block editor that won't work, as the HTML is just a representation of the title stored elsewhere, it's not a text input/form like the classic editor, it's a block, and if the posts title changes those DOM elements get replaced

Comment: I do believe you can split this question in 2, how to enqueue JS to run in the block editor is a self contained and much easier question to answer. Bundling your questions up can reduce the quality and number of answers you get as anybody writing an answer is forced to answer all of them at the same time. So if I knew how to do the multicolour part but not the enqueueing I couldn't write an answer and you'd miss out

Comment: also note that being able to change the colour of text is something a richtext component can already do, and it has a toolbar, as well as other formatting options. If you can add a richtext component in the post title block that would do this, but you'd need a large number of filters to strip out the tags to avoid things like mangled post slugs, broken RSS feeds, displaying raw HTML tags to users etc instead of formatting etc. I also expect what you've asked about to be quite an advanced/difficult thing to do, it may be easier to have a separate field for storing this